# SQL Server - database option "PageVerifyMode = 3" - Any reference for this?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, schema-compare

I'm comparing two different schema with Visual Studio 2010.

I got a difference in the database options, specifically:

`PageVerifyMode = 3 -- my source object`

`PageVerifyMode = 1 -- my target object`

Two questions here:

**1.How do the option impact the DB and what does the value 3 means?**

**EDITED:**
I have checked: `PAGE_VERIFY` is CHECKSUM in both the database so `PageVerifyMode` is different from `PAGE_VERIFY`.

**2. How do I change the value to mirror what I have in the source object?**

I cannot create the schema update script in Visul Studio because of an error related to my login and I could not find anything on internet except `set the PAGE_VERIFY to Checksum or torn page detection`.

Any help wiil be much appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you verified that value of 3 outside of VS? I ask because the documentation says that the valid values are (0, 1, 2) for (NONE, TORN_PAGE_DETECTION, CHECKSUM), respectively.

Comment: Thank you @BenThul - I will check soon. Could you link me the doc reference you were looking at please?

Comment: sys.databases - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx

Comment: @BenThul - I checked the PAGE_VERIFY option between the two database and they are the same, value is CHECKSUM for both. This means that PageVerifyMode is referring to a different option here, and this is why it allow 3 as a value. Problem now is that I cannot find anything on internet nor in the Doc...

Comment: Well… you're using VS to compare the databases. You can have VS create a script to sync the databases and see what it thinks the solution is to reconcile the difference.